# Como generar el template a partir de una imagen con Digital Persona y C#

Tags: c#

Tengo las imágenes de las huellas de los empleados, es posible generar el template a partir de estas imágenes usando el sdk de Digital Persona y lenguaje C#. ?

Comment: A que te refieres con template?

Comment: Es el binario con el que Digital Persona hace el match para verificar a una persona

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12627765/convert-finger-print-image-to-comparable-template

Parece que aqui hablan de eso, espero que te pueda servir, no es una respuesta exacta, pero podrias investirgar por allí.

Comment: Encontré que en GitHub hay varios proyectos que hablan de este mismo tema:
https://github.com/rtshadow/biometrics

pero están en otros lenguajes no en C#, esta interesante tu pregunta.

Comment: muchas Gracias @CristinaCarrascoAngulo estoy usando Neuro como sdk para reconocimiento facial, voz, huellas lo interesante es que es compatible con multiples sensores pero es necesario conectarse a un servidor de licencias (muy cara), para el caso de digital persona solo funciona con sus sensores pero es gratis y offline algo que necesito para un proyecto de baja escala.